# What is the relationship between Probabilistic Graphical Models and Graph Neural Networks?

Tags: graph-theory, neural-networks, bayesian-network

I would like to learn more about one or both of these. I incline towards Bayesian networks and PGMs but since Battaglia et al, 2018 I have had half an eye on the various kinds of GNN.

You seem to be able to do similar things with both PGMs and GNNs - inference and learning (of probabilities/weights and of structure) on graphs.  Do the two have different strengths?

Are they just rival academic camps? eg the new book "Deep Learning on Graphs" (Ma & Tang, 2021) doesn't have Koller & Friedman, 2009 in the bibliography & doesn't mention the term "graphical model".

Are the approaches complementary or antagonistic?

**References**

Battaglia et al., 2018, "Relational inductive biases, deep learning, and graph networks", https://deepmind.com/research/publications/relational-inductive-biases-deep-learning-and-graph-networks

Koller & Friedman, 2009, " Probabilistic Graphical Models: Principles and Techniques", https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/probabilistic-graphical-models

Ma & Tang, 2021, "Deep Learning on Graphs"  [http://cse.msu.edu/~mayao4/dlg_book/](http://cse.msu.edu/%7Emayao4/dlg_book/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers and comments have done a good job of highlighting how PGMs and GNNs are traditionally used in different settings.

However, there is a deep underlying connection between them: basic GNNs can be derived through embedded mean field variational inference on the joint distribution of the node features and their latent representations.

The work that first showed the above is [H. Dai, B. Dai, and L. Song. Discriminative embeddings of latent variable
models for structured data. In ICML, 2016].

Moreover, William L. Hamilton's incredible book "Graph Representation Learning" has an entire chapter dedicated to the theoretical motivations of graph neural networks, including spectral graph convolutions, PGMs, and the Weisfieler-Lehman graph isomorphism test.

Below I have summarised the main steps for this construction, which Hamilton (whose notation I use) and of course the authors of the paper explain in much greater detail.

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, a GNN tries to learn an embedding $z_u \forall u\in V$. From a probabilistic perspective, we can think of the embeddings as latent variables to infer, to explain the observed data, namely, the graph structure (adjacency matrix $A$) and input node features $X$.

More concretely, a graph defines a Markov random field:

$$p(\{x_v\}, \{z_v)\} \propto \prod_{v \in V}{Φ(x_v, z_v)} \prod_{(u, v) \in 
 E}{Ψ(z_u, z_v)}$$

where $Φ$ and $Ψ$ are non-negative potential functions. The above essentially says that the graph factors according to the graph structure.

In order to infer the distribution of latent embeddings, we will need to compute the posterior $p(\{ x_v\}, \{ z_v\})$ i.e. the likelihood of a set of embeddings given the observed features. This calculation is generally intractable, even with the right potential functions, so we resort to approximate inference.

We assume that the posterior over the latent variables factorizes into $V$ independent distributions, one per node:

$$p(\{ z_u\}, \{ x_u\}) \approx q(\{ z_u\}) = \prod_{v \in V}{q_v(z_v)}$$

To obtain the optimal $\{ q_v\}$, we proceed as usual by minimising the KL divergence:

$$KL[q(\{ z_v\}) || \{ p(\{ z_v\} | \{ x_v\})\} ] = \int_{(\mathbb{R}^d)^V}\prod_{v \in V}q(\{ z_v\})log\left(\frac{\prod_{v \in V}{q(\{ z_v\})}}{p(\{ z_v\} | \{ x_v \})}\right) \prod_{v \in V}{dz_v}$$

It can be shown through VI, that the $ q(z_v)$ minimising the KL divergence must satisfy the fixed point equation:

$$log(q_v(z_v)) = c_v + log(Φ(x_v, z_v)) + \sum_{u \in N(u)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}}{q_u(z_u)log(Ψ(z_u, z_v)} dz_u$$

which can be iteratively approximated through:

$$log(q_v^{(t)}(z_v)) = c_v + log(Φ(x_v, z_v)) + \sum_{u \in N(u)}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}}{q_u^{(t-1)}(z_u)log(Ψ(z_u, z_v)} dz_u$$

where $N(u)$ denotes the neighbourhood of node $u$ in the graph.

The remaining tool needed to make this work is to derive a sufficient statistic for the distribution $q_v(z_v)$ by embedding it in Hilbert space so that any computation carried out on the distribution can equivalently be carried out on its embedding.

The Hilbert space embedding of a distribution $p(x)$ on some $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is defined for some suitable feature map $\phi$ to make the embedding injective:

$$μ_x = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m}\phi(x)p(x)dx$$

By embedding $q_v(z_v)$ we can transform the fixed-point equation above to:

$$  μ_v^{(t)} = c + f(μ_v^{(t-1)}, x_v, \{ μ_v \forall u \in N(u)\})$$

Here, $f$ is a vector-valued function that aggregates information from the embeddings of neighboring nodes, which is then used to update the node's current embedding.

This corresponds exactly to a form of neural message passing!

We could then try to learn the Hilbert space embeddings that would correspond to a probabilistic model, but now we can define $f$ as a basic GNN:

$$μ_v^{(t)} = σ \left( W_{self}^{(t)}x_v + W_{neigh}^{(t)} \sum_{u \in N(u) }{μ_u^{(t-1)}}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks very much!  The maths is beyond me, but the two references look spot on.

Answer (score 2):

So PGMs and GNNs are very different. Don't let the names fool you :). The big application of Probabilistic Graphical Models (PGM), as far as I have seen, has to do with probability queries. One of the most common examples of a PGM is this situation where a person opens their door and finds the pavement wet. What is the probability that it rained outside, versus what is the probability that the sprinklers ran overnight.

In more realistic cases, there might be could be multiple noisy sensor inputs that give information about the state of a system. There could be correlation between the sensor readings, or different states could produce similarities between some sensor readings and differences in others, etc. Hence, by factoring the chain of relationships in the PGM, we can obtain more accurate probabilities for quantities/state of interest, given all of the inputs. The alternative might be some sort of logistic regression, but that would not necessarily incorporate the rich dependencies modelled by a PGM.

On the other hand, GNNs are used for a variety of different applications. There are common applications such as node classification and edge detection. For example, say you are looking at product recommendations and you want to classify whether a recommender is either legitimate or potentially nefarious/unreliable. If you look at the relationships that this recommender has with other known recommenders--and you know whether those known recommenders are reliable/unreliable--then you can classify the original recommender. Alternatively you can predict links between nodes based upon node level covariates and the existing pattern of links in the network.

There are of course may other applications of GNNs, and the two examples I gave are only a flavor of what you can do.

So PGMs and GNNs both incorporate information from the relationships between nodes, as well as node level information itself. But it is quite understandable that a person writing a book on GNNs would not cite the Koller and Friedman book, since the methods and applications are so different between models.

Comment: Structure learning (eg edge detection, node prediction) is a normal thing to use Bayesian networks (a kind of PGM) for isn't it?  Perhaps the graphs that GNNs are used for are not the kind of causal models that PGMs are used for.

Comment: @IvanUemlianin . Good question. So when I think of structure learning on graphs I generally don't think of edge detection or node prediction. What I have seen in my own experience, is that people have some data and they want to do some PGM model selection. So there are some graph energy metric that people use to determine how likely is the data given some graph structure. That is what I have seen, but I am sure people have used PGMs for edge and node prediction. Sometimes people want to estimate unmeasured or latent nodes from the observed predictions. That is possible both with PGM and GNN.

Comment: The idea of PGMs for probability queries seems to have gained more attention nowadays with respect to reinforcement learning and partially observed markov decision processes (POMDPs). If the "state" of a system is not fully known, then some ML folks have used PGMs as a way to estimate the state given observed information--and then do normal reinforcement learning. But I imagine that people could use PGMs for some node and edge prediction like you said.